# Performance of PBKDF2 c#.NET with

Tags: c#, security, encryption, hash, pbkdf2

> I need to implement a password hashing mechanism for our system. I am using `PBKDF2` for the purpose. I have made a small console application for the demo purpose. With the parameters I am using, Its taking my desktop `56 ms` to generate the final hash.
>
> From the sources I have gone through, they mentioned the generation time of 100ms should be reasonably secured. Is it the correct assumption or should I make my generation slower? If yes, what parameters should I probably change?

**CODE:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        byte[] op = null;
        op = GetPDKDF2("password", 20, 10000);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("total time: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static byte[] GetPDKDF2(string password, int saltSize, int iterationCount)
    {
        var pdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltSize, iterationCount);
        return pdf.GetBytes(20);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard delay to aim for is, as you said, 100ms.  The time taken to compute a hash with PBKDF2 is proportionate to the iteration count.  With this in mind, you could probably just double your iteration count to get a delay of around 100ms.

I suggest you don't allow the iteration count to change, at least not as an argument to the function.  Changing the iteration count in future, as hardware progresses, is a good idea, but you need to ensure the iteration count used is noted with the produced hash.

I'd use a constant value for the iteration count instead:

```
const int ITERATION_COUNT = 20000;
```

And use:

```
public static byte[] GetPDKDF2(string password, int saltSize)
{
    var pdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, saltSize, ITERATION_COUNT);
    return pdf.GetBytes(20);
}
```